# Atomicity in employing Paypal API

Tags: database, paypal, atomic

In the Paypal API, the flow allows opportunity for logging before an API call, sometimes in the middle, such as in the case of Express Checkout, and after a successful payment/transaction. I am concerned about the last step where confirmation of success of the call is received but perhaps was unable to be logged. I've been looking through the API but have not found a way to check the result of a previous payment/transaction. Is there such a call? How do I ensure atomicity in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API call is idempotent as of any version > 76.0; you can simply call it again a second time if you wish to verify the transaction really has completed.

Optionally, you can also employ PayPal [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) to get a server-to-server POST with data for each transaction happening on your account.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was researching and found the GetTransactionDetails operation, which seems useful. Any experience with that?